# Apache document root pointing to another server in the same network

Tags: apache, redirect

I need to do something but I do not how to refrase my question.
I have installed apach 2.4 on my laptop and the document root is in c:\Appache24\htdocs. I want to modify it that if I enter http://localhost or http://my_laptop_ip_address, get access to the files on my NAS storage server on 192.168.1.100.

Answer (score 0):

Though I am using Ubuntu and not Windows, I will suggest you to have a look at "Name-based hosts on more than one IP address." section in https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/vhosts/examples.html.